# Applescript to suppress double mails from different email addresses in smart mailbox "All Incoming"

Tags: applescript, mail.app, email

In my mail provider, I have two email accounts: one I use for my public email address: `myname@publicemailname` and one for my private email address: `myname@privateemailname`. (The `myname@publicemailname` is actually an alias of `myname@privateemailname` on the mail provider.)

Whenever a mail is forwarded to `myname@publicemailname` it also appears in the `myname@privateemailname` by my provider and that itself is okay. An email forwarded to `myname@privateemailname` is not duplicated to `myname@publicemailname`.

Then I created a "smart" mailbox "All Incoming" that contains both email addresses (and other email addresses).

How do I prevent the double mails from being included in the smart mailbox "All Incoming"?

I do not see a possibility of standardizing the rules.

The email in the `myname@publicemailname` is usually received slightly earlier than the email in the `myname@privateemailname`.

So I want to create a rule like this:
If the **To** address of the received email equals to `myname@publicaccountname` and the **From** address and timestamp (+ or - 1 second) equals the **From** address and timestamp (+/- 1 second) of the emails in the `myname@privateaccountname` then,
remove that email from the `myname@privateaccountname` in the smart mailbox **All Incoming**.

I have a little coding experience but I retired about a decade ago.